# df group by 2 columns and n.largest on 3rd column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem, this is my df

```
{'libelle_competence': {0: 'Accessoires automobile',
  1: 'Accueil téléphonique',
  2: 'Activités de remise en forme',
  3: 'Activités physiques et sportives adaptées',
  4: 'Activités physiques pour tous'},
 'Familles professionnelles': {0: ' Vendeurs',
  1: ' Professions para-médicales',
  2: " Professionnels de l'action culturelle, sportive et surveillants",
  3: " Professionnels de l'action culturelle, sportive et surveillants",
  4: " Professionnels de l'action culturelle, sportive et surveillants"},
 'prevalence comp': {0: 0.264107210349354,
  1: 0.25039387926072904,
  2: 0.5523925685283885,
  3: 0.5523925685283885,
  4: 0.5523925685283885},
 'prevalence comp %': {0: 26.410721034935314,
  1: 25.03938792607282,
  2: 55.23925685283866,
  3: 55.23925685283866,
  4: 55.23925685283866}}
```

I want to group by Familles professionnelles and libelle_competence and to add to sort the prevalence % column with nlargest(10) (only to keep the 10 first libelle competence)

```
df.groupby(["Familles professionnelles","libelle_competence"])["prevalence comp %"].nlargest(10)
```

but this is not what I want.

Edit : What I show is basically a head of my dataframe to dict. Here is what my df looks like:
[image]

the idea is to plot a graph for each 'famille professionnelles' when I keep only the top 10 libelle_competence that correspond to prevalence comp % . Is it better ?

Comment: I don't quite get what you want. I can execute your code snippet and it does exactly what I thought you wanted :D 
Your input data only has a single value per group. So basically, there is nothing to be done by restricting to 10 values. The output you expect would help a bit.

Comment: @maow I've edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby` will make pandas execute the following function for all groups. In your case, you want to discard a part of your `'libelle_competence'`-values. Therefore you should not put them into the groupby.

Using `nlargest` will absolutely work. If you want to keep the other columns though, you need to do a bit of formatting. I did something like this (using only the top 2 values so that something would get filtered :D)

```
In [14]: df.groupby('Familles professionnelles').apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2, 'prevalence comp %')).drop('Familles professionnelles', axis=1).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
Out[14]: 
                                 libelle_competence  prevalence comp  prevalence comp %
Familles professionnelles                                                              
 Professionnels de l'a...  Activités de remise e...           0.5524            55.2393
 Professionnels de l'a...  Activités physiques e...           0.5524            55.2393
 Professions para-médi...      Accueil téléphonique           0.2504            25.0394
 Vendeurs                    Accessoires automobile           0.2641            26.4107
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes thank you very much, and sorry for my bad explanation xD